# Open Source Language Translator API - For Java Application

Tags: java, api, machine-translation

Can anyone suggest a good open source language translator which could be used for translations from English to Spanish/German?

I am expecting a good reliable API to translate labels and messages in my application which I can easily implement. Please suggest!

Comment: Did you do a Google search? Did you find Google Translate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For English to Spanish conversion  ,Google API can be used. You can get the jar file for Google code
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/

Comment: OP said open source, not free. Not all open source is free. But I agree, a free one would be nice.